# Can oak leaves be used for winter compost without shredding?

Tags: leaves, mulch, oak

I planted six 8ft cherry laurels in the spring.  Do I need to mulch them for the winter and can I use unshredded oak leaves?  Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Shred them by mowing if you like, as oak leaves do break down slower than most leaves.